# HTACCESS Change URL to be more friendly but still send variable

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want to change this url:

https://www.ugocd.com/ilustracion?rubro=ilustracion

to be rewritten like this:

https://www.ugocd.com/ilustracion

but still send **rubro=ilustracion** because everything works with this variable in that page and I would like to have a general rule if its possible, because I have other similar pages:

https://www.ugocd.com/arte?rubro=arte

https://www.ugocd.com/animacion?rubro=animacion

https://www.ugocd.com/proyectos?rubro=proyectos

I've tried many things but nothing is working, could anyone please help me.

Thank you

I'tried lots of solutions but nothing worked, I expect to find a solution to my problem.

Comment: You should solve this in the application, not with htaccess. If you call https://www.ugocd.com/ilustracion the url doesn't work, so creating redirection in htaccess will not get you the result you want.

Comment: I'm sorry I dont understand. Where is the application? I want to tranform the url to a more friendly version but still send the variable that sends "RUBRO"

Comment: I finally could do it with this code:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sobre-mi$ sobre-mi?rubro=sobre_mi

it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a simple rewriting rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?ilustracion$ /ilustracion?rubro=ilustracion [L]
```

A generic approach would be something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)$ /$1?rubro=$1 [L]
```

It might be necessary to add a primitive form of a whitelist to prevent other URLs from getting rewritten:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(ilustracion|arte|animation|proyectos)$
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)$ /$1?rubro=$1 [L]
```

You may have to adjust those suggestions so that they fit your specific setup. You cannot expect that everything works out of the box when you just blindly copy something without understanding how the tools you are trying to use actually work.